# Fineness of topologies on eventually-zero sequences

Tags: general-topology

I'm doing self-study through Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*. There is a problem (12-10) where we exhibit a counterexample related to covering maps where I seem to be missing something.

The problem places two topologies on the space of eventually-zero sequences, $(x_i)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and only finitely many $x_i$ are non-zero.

$G$ uses the subspace topology from the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, and

$H$ uses the $l^\infty$ metric topology.

We are asked to

> Show that the identity map $G \to H$ is surjective and continuous with discrete kernel, but is not a covering map.

However, I have mostly convinced myself that the topology on $H$ is finer than the topology on $G$ and so the identity map should be continuous only in the *other* direction, so there is a continuous $H \to G$ that is not a covering map.

For instance, the neighborhood of radius 1 around $(0, 0, \ldots)$ in $H$ is an open set where every one of the infinite components is restricted to a proper open subset within $\mathbb{R}$. However, the product topology allows only finitely many of the components of an open set to be restricted to proper subsets, so I think this set is not open in $G$.

On the other hand, I think that all open sets in $G$ can be realized as a union of neighborhoods from $H$, because the open set $U_i \subset \mathbb{R}$ for each component $i$ in the product topology can certainly be build from neighborhoods under the metric topology.

Any insights into where I'm going wrong here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you’re working with the second edition, as this problem doesn’t appear in the first edition.

The [errata for the second edition](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Books/ITM/errata.pdf) say:

> ($9$/$16$/$14$) Page $335$, Problem $12$-$10$: Interchange the definitions of $G$ and $H$ in the sixth and seventh lines.
> (Otherwise, part (c) is false as stated.)

So it seems you’re right.